# C# equivalent to Apache HttpAsyncClient

Tags: c#, apache, http, asynchronous, persistent

I'm looking for a **C# library** that can do the same things of the **ApacheAsyncClient**.
It must handle **https** and support **persistent** and **asynchronous** http connections.

Basicaly i need a client that is able to receive server responses without making a request before and with the sun's HttpServer on server side and the ApacheAsyncClient on client side i was able to do this, but as i said i need a library for C#.
Does anyone know where can i find it?

Thank you ;-)

Comment: `HttpWebRequest`, `WebClient`, `EasyHttp` etc. Have you tried any one of them?

Comment: "a client that is able to receive server responses without making a request before": this scenario is not supported in the HTTP protocol... a client must always send a request for the server to send a response. Anyway, how would the server know to which client the response must be sent?

Comment: Not yet, but thanks for your advice, i praticaly never programmed in c# but i have to do this with this language, so i'm a little a newbie

Comment: @Thomas Levesque the server keeps in an object a cookie to recognise the client and in the same object keeps a PrintWriter created when the client first logins. This printwriter is used to send data to the client even if it didn't request it

Comment: Are you maybe looking for a HTTP client library that will allow Comet / HTTP streaming?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at SignalR https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR  I think it is probably the closest to what you are looking for.